# how to connect two programs (c++,qt)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, console, ipc

I have 2 programs. Console and QT. Console program should make some data , and qt program should than show this data. But this should be separate programs, and i do not know how can i tell QT program to do somthing from my Console. Two programs are local and Qt program is always running (so that i can not just run it every time), and Console is only lunched when needed. So the question is - how can i execute somthing in Qt after console program finishes? 
P.S. The console program makes a file that Qt program can read and than display.
I'm using windows.

Comment: Considered using [dbus](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/intro-to-dbus.html) ad inter-process communication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using something like [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qfilesystemwatcher.html) to poll for changes in a particular directory, then have your console program write the file there. That way the Qt program would get a notification when the contents of the directory change.

Answer (score 4):

Int Qt, you can start the console process with `QProcess`. That class has a [`finished`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#finished) signal, which you can connect to a slot in your application object. Then, when the console process finishes, the `finished` signal fires, and your slot function is called. At that point you can read the output file.

This is more efficient than a `QFileSystemWatcher` because you're directly watching the relevant event (console program finishes).

Comment: I actually also would prefer this over my own solution, but the catch naturally is that the console program must then be started from inside the Qt program, which makes non-interactive (e.g. scheduled) runs more complicated. Of course it can also be made to support both methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Interprocess Communication (IPC)** is the solution you're looking for.

The MSDN documentation is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574.aspx), containing more details about implementing this in your application, as well as code samples.

Answer (score 0):

This technique is called "Screen scraping". You are doing this by connecting console app's stdout to Qt apps input. 
Look at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at QSharedMemory: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsharedmemory.html. It allows inter-thread and inter-process communication.

A very nice and short example on how to use QSharedMemory is here: http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/ipc-sharedmemory.html